# Python SimpleActionServer stops unexpectedly (deadlock!)

Tags: python, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm writing a small piece of code that leverages actionlib, specifically SimpleActionServer. The main intricacy is that I register a preempt callback, but then I **set_preempted** on another thread (see code below).

However, when the rate of requests is relatively high (~1Hz) sometimes actionlib stops processings new requests. It does not crash, it does not print nor log anything, it just idles.

Below is a simplified version of my code:

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self):   
        self.server = actionlib.SimpleActionServer(
            "Topic", 
            Action,
            execute_cb=self.run,
            auto_start=False )

        #Variables so that preemption works
        self.myLock = threading.Lock()
        self.taskID = None

        #register preempt callbacks
        self.server.register_preempt_callback( self.stop )
     
        #Start actionlib
        self.server.start()
        
    
    def run(self, goal):      
        with self.myLock:
            self.taskID =  startTask() #Launch task in another thread
        
        #Wait for task to be completed or killed
        if not (self.taskID is None):
            wait( self.taskID ) #Wait for task to finish
        
        #Do not allow task to be preempted from now
        with self.myLock:
            self.taskID = None
        
        # Get actionlib result
        result = ActionResult()
        getResult(result)
        
        if not valid(result): #valid() defined elsewhere
            self.server.set_aborted( result )        
        elif self.server.is_preempt_requested() :
            self.server.set_preempted( result )
        else :
            self.server.set_succeeded( result )

        # Sometimes actionlib will stop processing new requests after this!!
                 
    
    def stop( self ):
        with self.myLock:
            if ( not ( self.taskID is None ) and self.server.is_preempt_requested() ):
                killTask( self.taskID ) # Function defined elsewhere
                self.taskID = None
```

Am I using actionlib in an invalid way? Could this be an actionlib bug?

Thanks,
Miguel S.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50276/python-simpleactionserver-stops-unexpectedly-(deadlock!)/) by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) on ROS Answers with karma: 1114 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-12-15**:
Just curious, which ROS distro are you using?

**Comment by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) on 2012-12-17**:
It's Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-12-25**:
Can you interrupt the program and get a backtrace?

**Comment by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) on 2013-07-12**:
@tfoote See my answer. @IsaacSaito Also present in Groovy in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a few months I sidestepped this problem. But today I've found the deadlock. I reckon there's a bug in [simple_action_server.py](https://github.com/ros/actionlib/blob/hydro-devel/src/actionlib/simple_action_server.py).

I wasn't able to get the python debugger to produce the stack traces that explained the problem. But after looking at the roslog debug messages and the source code, I came up with the following reconstruction of the events:

**Thread A (rospy's message dispatcher?)**

- Deadlocked in: `self.execute_condition.acquire()`
- In function: `SimpleActionServer.internal_goal_callback()` [simple_action_server.py:211] which was called from: `ActionServer.internal_goal_callback()` [action_server.py:293]
- This thread *has* `ActionServer.lock` and *wants* to acquire `SimpleActionServer.lock` (condition variable was initialised with the latter lock).

**Thread B (SimpleActionServer's executeLoop thread)**

- Deadlocked in: `with self.action_server.lock`
- In function `ServerGoalHandle.set_accepted()` [server_goal_handle.py:71] which was called from: `SimpleActionServer.accept_new_goal()`[simple_action_server.py:131] which was called from: `SimpleActionServer.executeLoop()`[simple_action_server.py:284] which at that point is holding `SimpleActionServer.lock`
- This thread *wants* `ActionServer.lock` and *has* `SimpleActionServer.lock`

In summary, if if a new goal arrives at the same time executeLoop is trying to get a previous (but still *new*, SimpleActionServer will deadlock.

I suspect the solution involves calling `accept_new_goal()` [simple_action_server.py:284] without holding `SimpleActionServer.lock`. My intuition is that simply setting a flag will do, but I will have to study the code a bit more to make sure there no side-effects.

I will try to code the solution myself unless someone fixes it quicker :)

Best,
Miguel S.

---

Originally posted by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) with karma: 1114 on 2013-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-12**:
Thanks for debugging into it.  I've opened a ticket here: https://github.com/ros/actionlib/issues/4

**Comment by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) on 2013-07-23**:
Issue has just been fixed! :)